# multivariate pdf that is sphere-like?

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question, marginal-distribution

While thinking about probability theory and probability distributions, I realized that I could name several multivariate distributions but could not name any multivariate distributions of genus $g=0.$ It could be that I don't know enough multivariate distributions, but it seems to me that distributions with $g=0$ are quite uncommon if not rare. What I mean by genus $0$ is that the topology of the shape of the distribution is sphere-like, (a sphere has genus $0$).

> Can anyone give me an example of a multivariate pdf with genus $0$?

Integrating over the enclosed volume of the distribution would give the total proability i.e. $1.$

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you mean. Are you asking for the level sets of your multivariate PDF $p(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to form a genus $0$ surface? If so, any density of the form $p=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 \right)$ with $f$ monotone will do as they are spherically symmetric. But this is not a necessary condition. Also, I think you'll need to generalize the notion of genus to higher dimensions if you want PDFs of arbitrarily many variables

Comment: You can just take the uniform distribution over a sphere.

Comment: @Sal I was hoping to obtain marginal distributions of the multivariate pdf under some conditions that the marginals are supported on $(0,1)^2$ s.t. $f(1)=0$ and $f(0)=1.$ Given this information, I believe I'd need the right copula to make the multivariate spherical-like distribution fit with the marginal information.

Comment: maybe the multivariate spherical-like pdf satisfies $f(0,1)=1$ and $f(1,0)=0$ as well.

Comment: I know that the level sets will be all be isotopic to a circle

Comment: I'd like if the bivariate pdf had support on $(0,1)^3$